Is it possible to force deletion of all unreachable objects in Git?
I have attempted the commands in this answer but it does not achieve the desired effect.
Consider a repository with dangling commits:
git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (179/179), done.
dangling commit 133e2422a9ce64d8e784d3a8f9af37b2d6812b19
dangling commit 71e42dc763ac71460f5e17751e5ae5de330134c8
dangling commit 0e9bd340ab447fcd158a59dbcb617c1e77a21c08
dangling commit 5c173ab15f032f36ffdaa16edae30df6382a8183
dangling commit 9f1babbe53fdcfa7eb8e470de50177fbd885ee36

I ran the following commands:
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git repack -a -d
git gc --aggressive --prune=now

Then I ran the git fsck and got the same results.
I am running git version 2.17.1.
Is there some variation of the gc command that will force deletion of these dangling commits?

Update: I upgraded git to git version 2.47.0 and observed the following behaviors:

git fsck  --no-reflogs shows the same dangling commits as before.
git fsck does not show any dangling commits.
git reflog shows no output.

That suggests that the commands for cleaning the reflog are simply not working as expected, although they do cause the output of git reflog to dissappear.

After trying a few more things and reading man git-repack as well as man git-prune, I found that the following worked on git 2.47 although I have no idea whether it will also work on the older git version.
git reflog expire --expire=now --expire-unreachable=now --all
git prune
git repack -ad

The result is that the old objects were finally purged!
$ git fsck --unreachable --full --no-reflogs
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (49/49), done.

Note that I have multiple working trees, so both of the commands below were insufficient:
# It looks like `--expire` is independent from `--expire-unreachable`.
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all

# This only affects a single worktree as far as I can tell.
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --expire=now

